# C#: how to handle floats properly

Tags: c#

In my code i write the following line:

```
return ((value / 120) * 1440).ToString();
```

Now this returns me 0 when the value in `value` is less than Zero because it treats the result of `(value / 120)` as an integer where as i need C# to treat this result as float is there any way to achieve this?

Example:
If Value = 80

Then, 
This function returns me `0` whereas i want this function to return me `960`

Comment: divide by 120.0 to force the division to be a float division.

Comment: Also as a tip, consider multiplying first before you divide to minimize the loss of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return ((value / 120.0) * 1440).ToString();
```

Comment: Seconds faster than me. Congratulations :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by 120.0(which is a double)

converts value also to double and divides

```
((value / 120.0) * 1440).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

or this:

```
float value = 80;
Console.WriteLine( ((value / 120) * 1440).ToString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want a single-precision float you can use `120.0f`, or `120.0` for a double-precision (double).

You can read up on floating-point literals for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`return ((value / 120.0) * 1440).ToString();`

or you can define value as float type.